# I need help getting video ids from a playlist in youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to fetch all the video ids from a playlist on YouTube. Currently, I have things almost working, except the ids that YouTube is returning a much longer than usual and don't seem to work. Here's part of my code:

```js
const requestUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=${process.env.KEY}&playlistId=${id}&part=id&maxResults=40`
```

The result under data.items looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    kind: 'youtube#playlistItem',
    etag: 'DxS1pY8G6dwZwfAUJeE8naJEvXM',
    id: 'T0xBSzV1eV9uUHdpaDVQbWY3aEJWQ1Q2LU14bVFOTGFBSVAwellYVGsuRUVCNzhFRENBQzBENDM4MA'
  },
  {
    kind: 'youtube#playlistItem',
    etag: 'hi9WR5RovxYzHpBXddP__e5nFSA',
    id: 'T0xBSzV1eV9uUHdpaDVQbWY3aEJWQ1Q2LU14bVFOTGFBSVAwellYVGsuQzVBOTAwNjQ1OTJFMTVBRg'
  }
etc...
```

However those ids are much longer than normal and when I go to for example

`youtube.com/watch?v=T0xBSzV1eV9uUHdpaDVQbWY3aEJWQ1Q2LU14bVFOTGFBSVAwellYVGsuRUVCNzhFRENBQzBENDM4MA`
the url automatically gets shortened to `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0xBSzV1eV9` and I get a video unavailable screen. When I changed &part=id to &part=snippet, the same thing happened, I just got more video info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want the [videoId property](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) rather than id.  So you'll need to modify your query string to return the resourceId section.  See the docs for details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.